# Overlays Adobe XD

Tags: adobe, adobe-xd

One of the features included in the new release of Adobe XD for June 2018 is the addition of overlays.. 
https://theblog.adobe.com/june-2018-release-adobe-xd-overlays-fixed-elements/

I can find a number of Youtube videos and articles for IoS, but nothing on Windows.. Does anyone know if this feature has already been included in the new release for Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes - I've used it on Windows. The feature is great but it's pretty limited in that you can only have one overlay active at a time. You can't do things like add an overlay within an overlay. It simply transitions the active overlay out before transitioning the new one in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes overlay feature is there.**

to do the same:

1. Create two artboards.
2. Go to prototype.
3. Select artboard and create link.
4. Select trigger(tap) from the prototyping menu.
5. Select Action(overlay) from the Prototyping menu.

[image]

Note: My Version is 14.0.42.14(Starter)